# Как не терять слово если оно не найдено в словаре(Полнотекстовый поиск Postgresql)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем мир! И очередной вопрос от меня.

Касается он в большей степени тех, кто уже работал с полнотекстовым поиском Postgresql

И вопрос таков:

Имеется некоторый конфиг полнотекстового поиска он использует несколько словарей и имеется слово "Том"(для примера) проблема в том, что ни один из словарей мне не выдает для этого слова лексемы.
В итоге, по запросу:

```
SELECT * FROM ts_debug('ru','Том');
```

я получаю пустой массив
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А хотелось бы, чтобы в случае, если слово не было найдено, то оно бы в чистом виде(с изменением регистра) попадало в лексемы. Каким образом это лучше сделать?

В добавок ссылка на Youtube с вопросом: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7243AxgDAgc (Сорри за сумбурность)

Comment: Вопрос решен... все оказалось намного проще. Есть еще словарь с названием "simple"

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен... все оказалось намного проще. Есть еще словарь с названием "simple", вот он как раз поможет